# bootstrap 5 popover needs to click twice before showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, popover

I'm having a problem with my popover script. needs to click twice before showing the popover content itself. take not that im passing a dynamic parameter to dynamic popover content.

html razor syntax element

```
@foreach (var data in Model.CapexRequests){
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class="popoverButtonApproval" id="popoverButtonApproval"  onclick="InitializeMyApprovalActionButtons('@data.RequestId','@data.Status')">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h text-primary"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
}
```

js

```
function InitPopover(requestId, status) {

let menuRequest = '<div style="display: none;" class="content">' +
    '<ul class="list-group">' +
    '<a class="link-actions optViewApproval" id="' + requestId + '|' + status + '">' +
    '<li class="list-group-item">' +
    '<span><i class="bi bi-eye"></i> View</span>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</a>' +
    '<a class="link-actions optApproveApproval" id="' + requestId + '|' + status + '">' +
    '<li class="list-group-item">' +
    '<span><i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up"></i> Approve</span>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</a>' +
    '<a class="link-actions optEditApproval" id="' + requestId + '|' + status + '">' +
    '<li class="list-group-item">' +
    '<span><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Edit</span>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</a>' +
    '<a class="link-actions optRejectApproval" id="' + requestId + '|' + status + '">' +
    '<li class="list-group-item">' +
    '<span><i class="bi bi-slash-circle"></i> Reject</span>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</a>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>';

$('#popoverButtonApproval').popover({
    "html": true,
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: 'bottom',
    "content": function () {
        return menuRequest;
    }
}).click(function (e) {
    $(this).popover('show');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you only initialize the popover only on first click

Comment: what possible piece of code im missing here? if you dont mind me asking.

Comment: You make a function with atribute onClick, so that function start only when click, so you only after that click popover will appear, you cand search for popover and add after .popover something to toggle to show not only after 2 click

Comment: So after that $('#popoverButtonApproval').popover add this line : `$('#popoverButtonApproval').popover('show');`

Answer (score 0):

move popover listener outside, add listeners there, only once, and return menu instead:

**EDIT:**

change popover buttons like this: add a class and your data in `data` attribute, instead of calling a function. and also maybe add a unique id to each button with `@{int i = 0;}`

```
@foreach (var data in Model.CapexRequests){
<tr>
  <td>
    <!-- maybe add a unique id to each button @{int i = 0;} -->
    <a class="popoverButtonApproval" id="popoverButtonApproval-@i"  data-requestid="@data.RequestId" data-status="@data.Status">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h text-primary"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
}
```

```js
function InitPopover(requestId, status) {

  return '<div style="display: none;" class="content">' +
    '<ul class="list-group">' +
    '<a class="link-actions optViewApproval" id="' + requestId + '|' + status + '">' +
    '<li class="list-group-item">' +
    '<span><i class="bi bi-eye"></i> View</span>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</a>' +
    '<a class="link-actions optApproveApproval" id="' + requestId + '|' + status + '">' +
    '<li class="list-group-item">' +
    '<span><i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up"></i> Approve</span>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</a>' +
    '<a class="link-actions optEditApproval" id="' + requestId + '|' + status + '">' +
    '<li class="list-group-item">' +
    '<span><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Edit</span>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</a>' +
    '<a class="link-actions optRejectApproval" id="' + requestId + '|' + status + '">' +
    '<li class="list-group-item">' +
    '<span><i class="bi bi-slash-circle"></i> Reject</span>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</a>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>';

}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.popoverButtonApproval').popover({
    "html": true,
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: 'bottom',
    "content": function() {
      return InitPopover($(this).data('requestid'), $(this).data('status'));
    }
  }).click(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('show');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<br>


<tr>
  <td>
    <a class="popoverButtonApproval" id="popoverButtonApproval-@i" data-requestid="@data.RequestId" data-status="@data.Status">
      <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h text-primary"></i>popoverButtonApproval
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>

<br>


<tr>
  <td>
    <!-- maybe add a unique id to each button @{int i = 0;} -->
    <a class="popoverButtonApproval" id="popoverButtonApproval-@i" data-requestid="@data.RequestId" data-status="@data.Status">
      <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h text-primary"></i>popoverButtonApproval
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thank you for this but im having a dynamic requestId and status.
 return InitPopover(requestId, status);

Comment: please also take note that im calling the function InitializeMyApprovalActionButtons() onclick through foreach loop. i updated my question. @traynor

Comment: @d'reaper check the updated code. also, there is no InitializeMyApprovalActionButtons... although I don't think you need it, jquery will assing all the listeners once the rendering is done